# Jquery post not wanting to send one of my paramaters

Tags: jquery

```
function createMessage(copySponsor) {
            var tolist = [];
            var distid = <%= Session("DistributorID") %>;
            var subject = $('#diaSubject').val();
            var message = $('#diaMessage').val();

            $("#toList > option").each(function() {
                tolist.push($(this).val());
            });
            alert(tolist + '\n' + copySponsor + '\n' + subject + '\n' + message);
            $.post('message_center_createMessage.asp', { messageList: tolist, distid: distid, subject: subject, message: message, copySponsor: copySponsor }, function(data) {
              alert(data);
            })

        }
```

The alert correctly shows everything, however the alert on the data shows everything bu the "messageList: tolist".  I don't think it is the server side code as i am correctly showing everything else just not the tolist.

Here is the information that is being passed into tolist: 516,519,373,374

I know the server code is correct:  But here it is.

```
Dim distID, _
    subject, _
    message, _
    bCCSponsor

    distID = request("distid")
    subject = request("subject")
    message = request("message")
    bCCSponsor = request("copySponsor")
    messageList = request("messageList")

response.Write(distID & "<br />")
response.Write(subject & "<br />")
response.Write(message & "<br />")
response.Write(bCCSponsor & "<br />")
response.Write(messageList & "<br />")
```

Thanks everyone for the firebug suggestion. Never knew firebug could give that information.

```
copySponsor true
distid  3
message asd
subject asd
tolist[]    516
tolist[]    519
tolist[]    373
tolist[]    374
```

Looks like it was an issue passing an object.  Thanks again.

Comment: Might help to post the server code since the jQuery seems fine and the first alert shows the data you need it to.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the server-side code if everything else is showing up OK in alert(data). Why don't you have a look at that server-side code and just make sure? Viewing the post in FireBug do you see the messageList transferred?

Comment: alert(data) is showing everything but 'messageList: tolist'.  I can only assume that for some reason the .post doesn't like posting the array from tolist.

Comment: I think that despite initially neglecting the server-side code, this didn't deserve downvotes! The question was fair, the client-side code was provided, and an answer of "You need to look on the server side" would be reasonably expected.

Comment: @GregPettit thank you, I agree.  I have also provided the server side code as requested.

Comment: Ok, I have found the answer.  Apparently the post did not like passing the array through.  I added this messageList: tolist.join(', ') and it seems to be working just fine now.  Is there a way to delete a question?  I can't answer it for 7 hours.

Comment: The tolist probably just needs to be a symbol-separated list (comma would be the obvious choice!). If it can be sent as (in query string format) `tolist=1,2,3,4&message=etc` then it should work. It's probably sending `tolist=[object Object]` or something like that. Use Firebug or another Network inspector to see exactly what is being sent, rather than relying on the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createMessage(copySponsor) {
            var tolist = [];
            var distid = <%= Session("DistributorID") %>;
            var subject = $('#diaSubject').val();
            var message = $('#diaMessage').val();

            $("#toList > option").each(function() {
                tolist.push($(this).val());
            });
            alert(tolist + '\n' + copySponsor + '\n' + subject + '\n' + message);
            $.post('message_center_createMessage.asp', { messageList: tolist.join(', '), distid: distid, subject: subject, message: message, copySponsor: copySponsor }, function(data) {
              alert(data);
            })

        }
```

Just needed to add the .join(', ') and it worked just fine.